# How to pass a div created with javascript to another page with php

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, html, css

I don't know how to display my divs in another page after created them. When the divs are created with their function, after clicking a button, they will be displayed in a div in the main page, right after that, there has to be a redirection to the second page, passing the divs created.

example how the main page works: [Jsfiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/0yc7s0cg/)

I don't know how to send and display the divs just created, in a second page.

I think that the action should be set with php but I don't know...

**IMPORTANT**

You don't have to understand the Js code. You only have to know that the divs that I want to copy to the second page, at the beginning, don't exist. So the "copy-to-the-new-page" action has to be done after the creation  of the divs.

Main Page:

```
<html lang="it">
      <head>
      <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
      <meta charset="UTF-8">
            <link rel="stylesheet" href="style.css"/>
        </head>
        <body>
<div id="faketxt" contenteditable>Write Here</div>
<button id='btn'>OK</button> <br>

<div id='boxes'>

</div>

<script type="text/javascript">

$('#btn').click(function() {
  var primo = document.getElementById('faketxt');
  var wordLimit = 145;
  var words = primo.textContent.replace(/(&lt;([^&gt;]+)&gt;)/ig,"").split(/\s/);
  if (words.length) {
    var count = 0;
    var div = createDiv();
    words.forEach(function(word) {
      if (++count > wordLimit) {
        count = 1;
        div = createDiv();
      }
      if (div.innerHTML) {
        div.append(' ');
      }
      div.append(word);
    });
  }
});

function createDiv() {
  div = document.createElement('div');
  div.className = 'fakes';
  document.getElementById('boxes').append(div);
  return div;
}

        </script> 

</body>
</html>
```

Comment: You have the `faketxt` input in your `download.php`. Why don't you just create it there? The div is just "random" markup, why would you want to pass that information?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You shouldn't have to send the entire div just the amount of data that's required for the next page to recreate it.
i.e. you could use a cookie and have the user remember:

```
document.cookie = "divinfo=The text field of the div's;\
                   path=/";
```

have a hidden input field that contained the relevant information.

```
<input name="divinfo" hidden value="The info required for the creation of the div"/>
```

If you use the cookie the javascript could recreate the data on the other side if you use the hidden input you should have the php recreate it.

Answer (score 0):

well, you have at least 3 ways to do it, and it all comes down to how to pass enough information between 2 pages:

1) you may get HTML of those divs when they are just created, store it in session storage, and re-create divs from the stored html. That way you dont have to know much about the divs on the 2nd page, but there is a limit on how much you can store. Also, may pose some security/privacy risks if information is sensitive, so you may have to do some extra coding to mitigate it.

2) you may re-create those divs on the 2nd page based on the same set of information you used to create those on the first page. JS code could be shared between the two.

3) use server side to generate div's content. That way you can generate both 1st and 2nd page content.

Or is there something I miss about the problem?

Answer (score 0):

1. Create a hidden text input in the submit form
2. Add the new div value to that hidden input
3. Submitting the form will send the value to the next page through php
4. Now pick that value in javascript using php like

   var xyz = '';
5. Now you can use this value whatever you want

I don't know why the values with php tag is not showing here :(

Comment: He already has all the information he needs in the `faketxt` input field. He just needs to read this field in the `download.php`.

Comment: var xyz = '<?php echo $_POST["faketxt"]; ?>';   In the second page, you just need to pick the value of php to the javascript through this piece of code. Then you can use this javascript variable however you want.

Answer (score 0):

I suggest a few changes. First all all, use a proper form - kind of like you had in the first revision of your question.

```
<form action="download.php">
  <input id="faketxt" type="text" value="Write Here" />
  <button id='btn'>OK</button>
</form>
<div id='boxes'></div>
```

Now, on the second page, you have all the information you need in your form field "faketxt" and just can create the divs there. Depending on which method you are using (POST/GET) you have access to the data [like following](http://www.w3schools.com/php/php_forms.asp):

```
<?php echo $_POST["faketxt"]; ?>
```

Secondly I suggest, you change you code slightly, to make it a bit more readable.

```
$('#btn').click(function() {
    var primo = document.getElementById('faketxt');
    var wordLimit = 5;
    var words = primo.value.replace(/(&lt;([^&gt;]+)&gt;)/ig,"").split(/\s/);

    while (words.length > 0){
       let div = createDiv();
       div.append(words.splice(0,wordLimit).join(" "));
    }
});
```

[See your modified fiddle.](https://jsfiddle.net/0yc7s0cg/1/)